# How to bend radial surround?

Tags: modeling

[image]I'm just learning blender(love it!), trying to bend this radial window surround to the dimensions shown. This fits into a radial wall. When I try bend, it doesn't look right(see above). What am I doing wrong? I've googled and youtubed but can't find anything. Thanks for any help[image: front ortho][image: top view]

Comment: Hello :). What exactly doesn't look right? And how did you try to bend it?

Comment: Hi...it's skewed instead of being uniform. See top picture. This is using an 86" empty. Seen someone on youtube do this. Trying to make it look like the "top view" pic. THANKS for your reply!

Comment: Hey :). Are you using the *Simple deform* modifier for the bending?